# Java read variable number values from text file and assign to declared program variables

Tags: variables, input, text-files

Is there a way in Java to have text file with listed a=10.35 b=20.57 c=30.79 and get program to only read the variable decimal values and assign them to declared variables a, b, c in the program.

Searched youtube found nothing.

Do not know if it is possible.

Do not know.

Got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly read in the contents of the text file and parse it down to the chars and doubles.

If you are referring to declaring named variables based on the file, there is no way to do this directly at runtime. You can, however, use a data structure like a [dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) or [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store the data and access it using the name as a key.

If you could provide more details about what you are trying to do, that would make it easier to answer your question more specifically.

Comment: Trying to read a text file with the following 3 separate lines, a = 5.5, b = 4.5, c = 3.5 and get the program to ignore the a =, b =, c = parts and only read in the decimal number values and put the decimal number values into the program variables a, b, c.